# google places - Get a list of street addresses from a lat/long

Tags: api, geolocation

I need to be able to search for addresses within the radius of 500M-1000M from a lat-long. Google places seems to be able to do this and give it to me in JSON which is awesome, but it is only returning businesses and establishments. I want every postal address in this radius. I have tried adding:
&types=street_address but it returns no results.

Is this possible and has anyone got any info on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [Google Maps API Web Services](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding)
 - in the [Viewport Biasing](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Viewports) section you can set bounds.