# Get a list of street addresses within a lat/lng radius

Tags: android, python, geocoding, android-location, reverse-geocoding

I'm developing a android application that uses the user location to show a list of street name suggestions around their coordinates, since location retrieval is not going to be accurate enough, and in my application i need the best accurate position.

I tried a lot of approaches, tested google reverse geocoder, but it only gives me only one address, i tried google places api but it's not intended to return addresses, but places, what's not i'm lookin for, i tried findNearBy streets of geonames, but it only gives me street names, i need full data of the streets, like, city, state, country... i tried to use both geonames and google geocoder, getting a list of names, and converting each name into reverse geocoder request, but some street names are also available in another countries, i dont know how to specify a name and a latlng in geocoder request to filter results near specific coordinate.

I tried apis on server-side, which is a django-python server, the scenario is: the user sends their coordinate to server, which will use user location to request to another api's and format the result to the android, but didn't manage to found a good and fast solution.

I've seen a lot of some similar questions on SO but none had the answers I am looking for.

Comment: how this is connected to Python?

Comment: **"...google places api but it's not intended to return addresses, but places"** yes, but places have addresses.

Comment: @PedroLobito but if the user coordinate is somewhere that dont have google places near, i cant display suggestions to the user

Comment: @wolendranh i have a django rest server

Comment: @PedroLobito using places e get the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900301/google-places-get-a-list-of-street-addresses-from-a-lat-long